# set up reactjs to heroku deployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku

I have been following this tutorial on how to setup a react app on heroku

https://medium.com/@chloechong.us/how-to-deploy-a-create-react-app-with-an-express-backend-to-heroku-32decfee6d18

I could run my working app locally and the deployment worked as well.

The problem is that I believe the server.js is serving the react application in a wrong way and I dont know how to fix.

---

SERVER.JS

```
const path = require('path')

// Serve static files from the React frontend app
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')))

// Anything that doesn't match the above, send back index.html
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/client/build/index.html'))
})
```

If I remove it, I will be able to access the endpoints and get a correct response, but the app frontend doesn't work.

If I leave that block, I will always get the same page back and the endpoints won't work.

```
http://doggosfacts.herokuapp.com/
```

---

REACT APP.JS

If I run my project locally, everything works.

What am I missing here?

---

Github Rep

https://github.com/ewerton-azevedo/dogsfacts

Comment: Very difficult to answer based on your question. Did you follow _all_ the steps? For example, did you include the `heroku-postbuild` in package.json's scripts section?

Comment: the application "works" on heroku. The problem I think is how the front end is being served from my server.
For example: If i delete that PATH block, I will be able to access the api normaly, but wont see my front end. 
If I leave that code block, my front end will always receive an entire html page instead of the json reponse.
I followed all the steps, but i think that this one dont fit my app.

Comment: Have you got a procfile?

Comment: No. I dont have one. I didnt see it on the tutorial...

Comment: Try adding a file called [`Procfile`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) to your root folder with one line in it: `web: node src/server/index.js -port 8000` (replacing that path with the path of your server file). It might not make a difference, but that's how my heroku app (react/express) works.

Comment: the log shows that the method get "/" returns 404.
I have no clue how to get that right now